# IKEA Billy DIY bookcases without bolting in a wall. Is it a good idea/safe?

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

Is it a good idea to buy a bookcase that is a DIY assembly for a large collection of big and heavy books?
Is it safe?
To be clear I am interested if the Billy bookcases of IKEA can be safely used for heavy books **without** bolting (L brackets or similar) it to the wall.
Does it depend on the height? Would something like bookshelf shims be needed/help?

Comment: How can we possibly guess? Quality is everything.  The walmart model, probably not.  The Ikea model, probably.

Comment: @Harper: Yes, the ikea. That's where my question comes from. I found that online some say it needs to be supported by screwing the top in the wall so I am not sure if it is an issue in IKEA or any assembly bookcase

Comment: @Harper: I updated the post

Comment: My comment above addressed an earlier version of this question, it was completely rewritten and my comment is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 7):

### Screwing to the wall has nothing to do with capacity

Think about it. The furniture isn't necessarily directly against the wall, and a screw or very thin bracket reaching across some distance isn't going to carry much weight *in shear*. I.E. the wall doesn't ordinarily bear any weight.

### It's about safety

Ikea has a **very strong** message about standing furniture being screwed into the wall.  You didn't quite get the whole message.  It's **to prevent furniture from toppling over and killing someone**. Furniture topples over when its center of gravity goes outside its feet.  Examples of how that happens:

- It isn't level
- the floor sags under the weight
- someone grabbing the furniture to catch their balance or pull themselves onto their feet
- Someone (e.g. child) trying to climb the furniture
- All the drawers open
- Heavy items in an *open* drawer not counterbalanced by heavy items in closed ones
- Use in a mobile structure (boat, RV, #vanlife, "tiny house" on wheels)
- Earthquakes
- The top heavily loaded when the bottom is not (greatly amplifying the above)

**Every** piece of furniture from **every manufacturer** of the same size will have **the exact same problem** -- that is *basic physics*.  The only reason it's such an intense thing for Ikea is, they have chosen to invest heavily in their brand, which makes them targetable.  Likewise, people are sickened by Mexican food trucks and burrito shops every day - but it only makes the news when it's Chipotle.

Comment: But bookcases that are sold by regular stores which are not assembly and are standing don't have any such brackets to be bolted on the wall (or even warning from the store). Why is that?

Comment: Same problem for all furniture.  Those other "brands" use a different liability model called "have no assets". 1) find an untaken domain name 2) register an LLC, rent office, design logo 3) get a catalog from a Chinese manufacturer 4) pitch it to big-box stores and haggle price 5) dropship products from China straight to big-box 6) distribute profits to shareholders immediately 7) get sued 8) declare bankruptcy 9) **walk away** 10) find an untaken domain name

Comment: IKEA has been sued over a death in such an accident.  
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2016/12/22/ikea-to-settle-for-50-million-after-its-dressers-tipped-over-killing-three-young-boys/

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2934936/Distraught-parents-young-children-killed-falling-items-furniture-TV-sets-rally-raise-awareness-tip-deaths.html

Comment: @Harper: I am talking about physical stores that sell standing cases build by a carpenter. They don't mention anything about bolting to the wall. Is it because of quality?

Comment: @Jim no, it's not because of quality, it's because of physics and geometry.   It wouldn't matter if the bookshelf was made by NASA out of titanium honeycomb.

Comment: @Harper:Interesting. I was around standing furniture handmade that was too heavy to even move (not bookcase). I thought that self-assembly made a huge difference. But to be fair I don't think I never thought of what would happen if someone climbed on them

Comment: Self-assembly makes a big difference. Not in quality, stability, etc. But rather that someone who gets Ikea (or Bush or any other brand of assemble it yourself/flat-pack furniture) will see the "secure it to the wall" instruction as **part of the regular process**. If you buy fully-assembled furniture then it may well come with a "for your safety and our lawyer's peace of mind, please secure this to the wall" notice on the other side of the warranty notice that everyone ignores - but it isn't obvious like it is with Ikea, etc.

Answer (score 3):

They can be used without bolts as long as no one is trying to climb the front of the bookcase. Something which greatly correlates with the amount of children in the vicinity

Comment: So this is the only issue? The number and weight of books is not relevant? E.g. **fully** loaded with big and heavy books, end to end, top to bottom no free space at all

Comment: Correct. The books only push downward. Kids climbing on it exert torque.

Comment: Do you own a Bill case?

Comment: Worst case scenario for center of gravity: a large **tube** TV (large tube TVs have very thick glass, all the weight is in the front) and a child climbing on an open drawer.  http://hollywoodlife.com/2016/06/28/ikea-dresser-recall-toddler-children-dead-deaths/

Answer (score 3):

I have 7 Billy cases with extensions around the house. They are not bolted and full of books. Feels perfectly safe, but it may be just me - the huge believer in Darwinism. If you don't trust household occupants to never pull on the shelves and bury themselves in books or other items with a case on top, you should bolt them to the walls.

Comment: I was wondering if the actual contents could be an issue. E.g fully filled, or fully filled and removing some books from bottom selves or something that could be of concern

Answer (score 1):

These book cases are not very stable. We have doors on ours and if the bookcases are empty and the doors are open they will fall forward. Putting books in will push the CG backwards however my recommendation is to use the wall brackets to be sure they don't toople over - better safe than sorry!!!

Answer (score 0):

The risk with a bookcase depends on a number of factors.

1. How tall is it? a taller bookcase is higher risk than a shorter one. It appears that the billy comes in two heights, 106cm and 202cm, I would consider the 106cm to be low risk, but the 202cm to be much higher risk.
2. How heavy is the bookcase and it's load. Weight can be a double edged sword, a heavier bookcase will do more damage if it falls, but weight makes it harder to tip in the first place. In particular filling the lower shelves first makes it safer, filling the upper shelves first makes it more dangerous
3. How deep is it, deeper is more stable because it has to tip further before tipping over.
4. Who is using the space, you have to be more careful if children are around.